# Show Hide Divs jQuery (Change image for each link)

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show, selected

I'm currently using this piece of code to show and hide divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/3120/

I'd also like to have a custom image sprite for each link when it's selected. I tried giving each link it's own ID and with a background image but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<a id=“btn1” class="showSingle" data-target="1">Option 1</a>

#btn1 { width:147px; height:172px; background: url(../img/btn1.png) no-repeat top; display:block;  }
#btn1 .selected { background-position:bottom; }
```

Can anyone help me modify/add-on to this code to achieve what I want?

Comment: You are trying to add an image to the div or ? background ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should not be a space between `#btn1 .selected`,
it should be `#btn1.selected`

Comment: Perfect! This worked! Looked like it was just that little mistake.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a background image added do the following:

```
$('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).show();
    // adding the background.
    var imageURL = 'someURL';
    $('#div' + $(this).data('target')).css("background-image", 'url(' + imageURL + ')');
});
$('.showSingle').first().click();
```

Hope that helps

Comment: then set the url as a variable will changed my solution